# getting ActionView::MissingTemplate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a method called `def createCustomer` so i created a .html.erb file called createCustomer within the folder name `charge` which is the name of the controller. This `charge` folder is in under the `views` folder.

i am getting this on my logs

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template charge/createCustomer, application/createCustomer with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: 2016-01-26T23:00:34.324498+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/app/views"
```

Comment: Why don't you use Rails' (and Ruby) naming conventions and name your methods with underscore (`create_customer`) instead of camel case?

Comment: my bad, im still new to it. Im coming from iOS. ill change it. Is that the issue?

Comment: Do you have `get 'charge/createCustomer'` in `route.rb` or respond_to do |format| format.html end in `createCustomer` method?

Comment: I also have a same issue anyone solve that..plz give some details about that

Answer (score 0):

To add to the comments, you need to equate yourself with the Rails infrastructure ([convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration)):

- Class names are [`CamelCase`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), file names are [`snake_case`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)
- Controllers are `plural` (mostly)
- You should keep your controllers [`resourceful`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)

---

Here's how it should be structured:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :customers #-> url.com/customers/new

# app/controllers/customers_controller.rb
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @customer = Customer.new
   end

   def create
      @customer = Customer.new customer_params
      redirect_to @customer if @customer.save
   end

   private

   def customer_params
      params.require(:customer).permit(...)
   end
end

# app/views/customers/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @customer do |f| %>
   ...
```